# Why does MPMoviePlayerController stutter when first playing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

After making some simple changes to an app, the `MPMoviePlayerController` has begun stuttering when playing videos. The problem only happens about 10% of the time, and so far I haven't discovered any repeatable pattern. The stutter just happens at the beginning: the video starts, and then after about a second, it restarts. That's it.

Here's my setup code, as called from `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.moviePlayerController=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];    
[self.moviePlayerController setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
[self.moviePlayerController setShouldAutoplay:NO];
[self.moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
[self.moviePlayerController.view setAlpha:0];
[self.moviePlayerController.backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

And then when the user taps a big play button:

```
[self.moviePlayerController play];
```

I've combed through all the code many times, setup up many `NSLogs` and breakpoints, and don't appear any closer to solving the problem. Why has this started happening? Has anyone else had this issue with `MPMoviePlayerController`? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Don't know if it will work or not, but try to put KVO on your player, in the state (play/pause), and moviePosition ?

Comment: Hi @Larme, I print out the `currentPlaybackTime` and `playbackState` every 20 ms and the stutter always occurs in the first second. I see the playback time jump back down to around 0, and the playback state remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up swapping out `MPMoviePlayerController` for `AVPlayerViewController`. Pretty straight-forward to do, and the stutter is now gone.